# replace multiple occurrence of duplicate string in Scala with empty

Tags: scala

I have a string as

```
something,'' something,nothing_something,op nothing_something,'' cat,cat
```

I want to achieve my output as

```
'' something,op nothing_something,cat
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, here's one approach with the following steps:

1. Split the input string by "," and create a list of indexed-CSVs and convert it to a Map
2. Generate 2-combinations of the indexed-CSVs
3. Check each of the indexed-CSV pairs and capture the index of any CSV which is contained within the other CSV
4. Since the CSVs corresponding to the captured indexes are contained within some other CSV, removing these indexes will result in remaining indexes we would like to keep
5. Use the remaining indexes to look up CSVs from the CSV Map and concatenate them back to a string

Here is sample code applying to a string with slightly more general comma-separated values:

```
val str = "cats,a cat,cat,there is a cat,my cat,cats,cat"

val csvIdxList = (Stream from 1).zip(str.split(",")).toList
val csvMap = csvIdxList.toMap

val csvPairs = csvIdxList.combinations(2).toList

val csvContainedIdx = csvPairs.collect{
    case List(x, y) if x._2.contains(y._2) => y._1
    case List(x, y) if y._2.contains(x._2) => x._1
  }.
  distinct
// csvContainedIdx: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 7, 2)

val csvToKeepIdx = (1 to csvIdxList.size) diff csvContainedIdx
// csvToKeepIdx: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 5)

val strDeduped = csvToKeepIdx.map( csvMap.getOrElse(_, "") ).mkString(",")
// strDeduped: String = cats,there is a cat,my cat
```

Applying the above to your sample string `something,'' something,nothing_something,op nothing_something` would yield the expected result:

```
strDeduped: String = '' something,op nothing_something
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an `Array` of words separated by commas using `split` command on the given `String`, and do other operations using `filter` and `mkString` as below:

```
s.split(",").filter(_.contains(' ')).mkString(",")
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val s = "something,'' something,nothing_something,op nothing_something"
s: String = something,'' something,nothing_something,op nothing_something

scala> s.split(",").filter(_.contains(' ')).mkString(",")
res27: String = '' something,op nothing_something
```

As per Leo C comment, I tested it as below with some other `String`:

```
scala> val s = "something,'' something anything anything anything anything,nothing_something,op op op nothing_something"
s: String = something,'' something anything anything anything anything,nothing_something,op op op nothing_something

scala> s.split(",").filter(_.contains(' ')).mkString(",")
res43: String = '' something anything anything anything anything,op op op nothing_something
```

Comment: What if there were, say, 3 "op"s and 4 "anything"s in the string?

Comment: @Leo C Can you please provide an example string?...As per the requirement in the question, this works ..I Hope.